# Data in executable file are on weird position

Tags: c, assembly, linker, exe, portable-executable

Few days ago I've started playing with PE format. I've done small PE loader which is able to load sections to memory according to their virtual addresses. For example I have section `.text` on virtual address `0x1000`, or section `.data` on `0x2000`. With my small assembly code, I've loaded PE file on some free location (`0x10000`) and I loaded PE sections from it's positions. So, section `.text` is on `0x11000` (`0x10000 + 0x1000`), `.data` is on `0x12000` etc... But when I referenced my data in assembly from `.code` location, I found out (in disassembly) that it's pointing to `0x402000`. On internet I found something like image base which is specific for each type of image... But I don't understand how can be `.exe` loaded to `0x402000` when there are lots of executables running in Windows for example. Does anybody why is it so, how does it work and how can I teoretically implement it in my very basic system?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual memory means that every single process on your computer can use the "same" addresses, since the address spaces of each process are independent. 0x400000 for process A is mapped to a different *physical* address than 0x400000 for process B by the OS, even if they are the same virtual address (different virtual *address spaces*).

The default *base address* for an executable is 0x400000. Your linker hardcodes that base address into the executable and will adjust address references appropriately. Your executable will be loaded at that address when the program is launched. Your assembler or linker should give you a way to change this default base address.

Note that DLLs, on the other hand, have to be loaded at unique addresses because they must coexist in the same process. For this reason, DLLs are normally *relocatable*, i.e. they can have any base address when loaded to cope with the requirement of putting them at a unique address. (Having multiple non-relocatable DLLs on a system can cause problems, but having multiple non-relocatable .exes on a system is no problem at all.)

Comment: ok, and how is the OS doing that normal assembly instruction is addressing different location? How is this possible?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. It's a function of the linker, not the OS. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok but still. If it is not physical address, how does the CPU know where should it read/write bytes from/to?

Comment: [Read Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Memory) and/or take an OS course. The topic is too big to cover in an SO answer.

Answer (score 3):

Each executable runs in its own [virtual address space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912%28VS.85%29.aspx). So even if two executables have the same image base of 0x400000, they reside/use different physical memory. Think of it as the base of the image base differs.

To get the image base of a module loaded into your running process you can use [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28VS.85%29.aspx). It returns a handle to the module which incidently equals the image base. Alternatively you can get the image base from the ImageBase field in the PE Headers IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER structure ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)).

Comment: ok, and how is the OS doing that normal assembly instruction is addressing different location? How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated subject, but because of virtual memory and hardware aided separation of processes, every process is loaded and it is given the impression that it has the entire address space to itself.  Therefore all image bases can start at the same address, because the addresses in virtual memory can be mapped anywhere to memory, and the process has infinite memory as far as it is concerned.

Comment: Infinite up to the limit of the VM space, which is really not so big anymore for 32-bit processes.

Comment: ok, and how is the OS doing that normal assembly instruction is addressing different location? How is this possible?

Comment: @user35443 there is something called Address Layout Randomization, which loads things to different address each time it's loaded.

Comment: I meant that ASM instruction is always same. But how does the CPU know that where in the physical memory is the location `0x402000`.

Comment: because the virtual address gets translated to physical memory with the help of specialized hardware